# Laravel/PyroCMS Webserver and PHP Composer Permissions

Tags: laravel, apache, composer-php, file-permissions, pyrocms

Could anyone help me with some unix permission stuff? I’ve been struggling with it for months now and can’t get it quite right.

My web server is running as `www-data` in the `www-data` group and I do my composer stuff as a user called `finn` with sudo privileges (but I definitely don’t sudo composer :joy:).

From what I read, it is often easier for a user to own all the files/directories but for the user to be in the `www-data` group, so to that effect I have written a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo chown -R finn:www-data /srv/pyrocms
sudo usermod -a -G www-data finn
sudo find /srv/pyrocms -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /srv/pyrocms -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Where the aim is to
1. Make me own everything
2. Add me to the `www-data` group
3. Set read/execute permissions
4. Change the group to `www-data` for the all important `storage` and `bootstrap/cache`
5. Give me and the `www-data` group read/write/execute permissions on `storage` and `bootstrap/cache`

*The problem!*
After doing `composer update` as the `finn` user I often get problems where the web server cannot write to cache files in `storage/streams/{site-slug}/cache/` and it kicks the bucket throwing 500 errors.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have sudo privileges and you're using sudo, it may be easier to login as `www-data` user and do all tasks as `www-data`. There will be no problems with privileges if everything will be owned by `www-data`:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash www-data
composer install
```

---

Alternatively (and probably better) option would be to create dedicated user (like `www-finn`) and always run PHP as `www-finn`. It should be pretty easy to achieve, if you're using php-fpm for running PHP processes for handling web requests:

```
[www-finn]  
user = www-finn
group = www-finn
...
listen.owner = www-finn
listen.group = www-finn
```

Add `www-data` to `www-finn` group so webserver will have access to `www-finn` files. And then make `www-finn` owner of your web app:

```
usermod -a -G www-finn www-data
sudo chown -R www-finn:www-finn /srv/pyrocms
```

Comment: This shouldn't work. At least on my server I couldn't run it with a similar config.

Comment: Thanks rob006! I see both you an Piterden have the idea of running PHP-Fpm as my user so I’ll look into doing this!

Answer (score 0):

You should run `composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms pyrocms` from `/home/finn/srv` folder and under `finn` and definitely NOT sudo user (`finn` may be sudoer or not it is don't matter).

PHP-FPM pool config:

```
[finn]
user = finn
group = finn

listen = /run/php/finn-fpm.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Nginx host config:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_param     SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  fastcgi_pass      unix:/run/php/finn-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index     index.php;
  include           /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Then you may not change any permissions under your `finn` unix user, but if there would be troubles, just run next under `finn` user:

```
find /home/finn/srv/pyrocms -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /home/finn/srv/pyrocms -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod -R /home/finn/srv/pyrocms/storage 777
chmod -R /home/finn/srv/pyrocms/bootstrap/cache 777
chmod -R /home/finn/srv/pyrocms/public/app 777
```

Also, please notice about you would need sudo only for edit your configs under `/etc` folder.

Comment: Thanks Piterden! Are there any concerns about running PHP as a priviliged user? And why does it have to be 777 on those folders? Why does the world need read/write/execute when surely having the user/group read/write is enough?

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean about running php as a privileged user. Your php-fpm service is running under root, anyway.

Comment: Ha, and could you explain me, why your `finn` group needs those permissions? We talk only about `finn` user and not group. Also, why do you have 664 and 775? The right permissions should be 640 and 750

Comment: I’ve changed to using 644 and 755 like in your example  The finn group probably doesn’t need those permissions you’re right

Comment: Not quite - I don’t use FPM at the moment. The default Apache config was with mod PHP7 so I’m just figuring 